# filtering/discarding some rsyslog messages

Tags: rsyslog

In python using rsyslog I am logging error messages from postfix. However some error logs are broadcasted multiple times with minor changes in it like this:

```
postfix/error[34864]: 45E23361509: to=<sample@mail.com>, relay=none, delay=1.1, delays=0.01/1/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
postfix/error[34864]: 45E23361509: to=<sample@mail.com>, relay=none, delay=17, delays=17/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
postfix/error[34864]: 45E23361509: to=<sample@mail.com>, relay=none, delay=37, delays=37/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
```

These are same error logs for only one postfix mail attempt. If one mail operation goes wrong I receive like 7-8 error logs only delay value changed. I want to log only one of them.

Can you offer me a solution? Maybe like a configuration in rsyslog filters.